# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute * python

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, python, installation

I am struggling with compiling python 2.7.9 from source and have been advised to ask [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890225/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-python) question here.

While installing python 2.7.9 following the steps described [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/python2.html) the following errors occurred:

```
python make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

I tried reinstalling the previous version of python:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall  python2.7-dev
```

The installation proceeded normally. However, now, when trying to **import hashlib** I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server.py", line 5, in <module>
    import hashlib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 138, in <module>
    _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
```

I am also unable to install any packages using **pip** as the only output provided is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I installed **python-setuptools**:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

**pip** still provides the same output regardless of the input. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg) question I ran:

```
curl -O https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
chmod +x ez_setup.py
python ez_setup.py
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 49, in <module>
    import hashlib as _hashlib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 138, in <module>
    _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
```

Where is the issue?

**Edit #1:**

The output of **sudo apt-get install --reinstall  python2.7-dev** seems normal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjs-sphinxdoc linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 310 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/269 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 219657 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7-dev_2.7.6-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-dev (2.7.6-8) over (2.7.6-8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up python2.7-dev (2.7.6-8) ...
```

**Edit #2:**

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544378/uninstall-python-built-from-source) which tackles a similar issue. It points to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7635985#post7635985) thread which uses a **checkinstall** in order to retrieve all written files and creating a .deb package from them:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall  # install the checkinstall package
cd /home/user/Python-2.7.9
sudo checkinstall -D --fstrans=no make install   # make the deb package
```

Upon running the last command the output provided is identical with the one given by **make install**:

```
...
Listing /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/__init__.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/expat.py ...
Listing /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/__init__.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/_exceptions.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/handler.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/saxutils.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xmllib.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

**Edit #3:**

It appears that all scripts are unable to run. I am working on signing algorithms(used in bitcoin) and the tools mentioned [here](http://blog.richardkiss.com/?p=371)(bu, tx) are all outputting the same error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/bu", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

**Edit #4:**

I have also tried the approach mentioned [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27552). The output of **python get-pip.py**
is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 49, in <module>
    import hashlib as _hashlib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 138, in <module>
    _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
```

If I comment the line:

```
import tempfile
```

then execution continues up to line 141:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 19892, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 141, in main
    tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
NameError: global name 'tempfile' is not defined
```

meaning that the import of the following libraries:

```
import os.path
import pkgutil
import shutil
import sys
import struct
# import tempfile
```

succeeds. This makes me believe that the installation of python2.7.9 is only partially complete(as wisely suggested in the comments to this question).

**Edit #5:**

I have reran the configuration and compilation steps:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr       \
            --enable-shared     \
            --with-system-expat \
            --with-system-ffi   \
            --enable-unicode=ucs4 &&
make
```

The builds terminates with:

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
bsddb185           dl                 imageop         
sunaudiodev                                           
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

running build_scripts
```

Are these modules essential?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890225/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-python